# How to do Unit testing in Object Box for flutter project?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, flutter-objectbox

How can we do unit testing for object box in flutter project for all crud operations?

```
class ShapeRepo {

final _box = store.box<ShapeModel>();

void saveShape(ShapeModel model) {
    _box.put(model);
}
```

This is one example. There are many box operations. I was wondering if a separate object box store is available for testing?

Comment: Can you use the real ObjectBox database with a test database (another file name)?

Comment: Do you mean that we clear all data from the store, populate it with test data and then run the box operations and query operations on the test suite separately ?

Comment: Even if I do that, do I have to run the simulator or device to provide the path for the store initialisation or is there a facility to provide the local path, such that object_box_test.mdb file is created inside test folder or something like that.

Comment: Should look something like this: `final store = openStore(directory: 'myTestDirectory')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [Flutter's unit-testing guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/unit/introduction), you can adapt it to your project. Say you have some classes depending on ObjectBox in the `lib` folder. In that case, just create your test cases for `package:test` as you normally would, and provide a locally opened database: just import `openStore` from your `lib/objectbox.g.dart` (or wherever you have the generated code. The database will be saved in the current directory (in the `objectbox` subdirectory), unless specified otherwise. It is good practice to delete this directory in the `tearDown` function of the test group.

Considering the class you've posted in the question - it must get the `store` from somewhere, right? So for example you'd give the store opened in the test folder as a constructor argument.